# How to set up traffic forwarding so my origin IP address remains the same when calling an external API from Azure or my laptop

Tags: azure, routes, forwarding, traffic, vnet

I have an Azure App Service and multiple Azure Functions that need to call into a specific external API - let's call it *external.api.com*. I also frequently run the App Service and Azure Functions locally on my laptop during development/debugging etc.

My issue is that I can only have one IP address whitelisted to use this external API.

What is the best way to set up some kind of Virtual Network (or something else?) in Azure to enable all calls to this external API to have the same origin IP address?

I have seen tutorials on ways to do this from internal Azure services/functions, however I haven't been able to see anywhere that explains how to do this for calls from both internal Azure services/functions AND from external IP addresses (i.e. my laptop).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to look for a proxy that would mask your ip.

Comment: Yeh this is exactly what I want, just I'm not sure how to set it up in Azure